# India states map in Google geomaps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I would like to create a interactive geo map. I have already created world map as

```
region: 'world',
displayMode: 'regions'
```

And also created a map for india as markers

```
region: 'IN',
domain: 'IN',
displayMode: 'markers',
```

Now I need to create a map for india as regions instead of markers.
Now here is the problem with markers:-

I have successfully created it but there are some states which missing in that like uttarakhand, chhatisgarh and telangana. Can anyone help with that, here is the link to jsfiddle which is showing the map for indian states [fiddle for map](https://jsfiddle.net/jitendravyas/f5ZLn/)

Comment: @Mikel Is it possible to view districts in a state using this, specifically for Indian states?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The map works, but some names can be wrong. I recommend you to use the ISO codes to avoid those problems: `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2:IN`

You can create the data in this way:

```
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['State Code', 'State', 'Population'],
    ['IN-UT', 'Uttarakhand', 10116752],
    //rest of states
  ]);
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f5ZLn/816/)

Tell me if it helps you.